# How do I reset my values in a switch statement?

Tags: java, random, boolean

I'm working on a stacking boxes games that uses a random number generator but I can't get my program to reset whenever a number is used twice?

1)  Pick an implementation of either tracing the boxes as they are created or going directly to a solution.
2)  A while loop controls the next three steps.
3)  Pick a box
4)  Determine if this box can be placed
5)  Place a box
I used 6 boolean variables each one representing a box.  A switch statement called one of 6 methods depending on the random number given for a box.  These six methods analyzed the current stack of boxes and determined which one of the 13 box combinations to call.

```
package com.chinus;

i
    private static void trace() {
        int boxesUsedSoFar = 0;
        boolean gameIsDone = false;
        int usedOnce;

        while (gameIsDone != true) {
            int number = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            boxesUsedSoFar++;

            System.out.println("Current Box Number : " + number);
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    if (number == 1) {
                        box1 = true;

                    }
                    if (box1 == true && box2 == true && box3 == true) {
                        combo6();
                    } else if (box1 == true && box2 == true) {
                        combo4();
                    } else if (box1 == true && box3 == true) {
                        combo7();
                    } else if (box1 == true) {
                        combo1();
                    }
                    else{
                        restart();
                    }
                    box1=false;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (number == 2) {
                        box2 = true;


                    }

                    if (box1 == true && box2 == true && box3 == true) {
                        combo6();
                    } else if (box1 == true && box2 == true) {
                        combo4();
                    } else if (box2 == true && box3 == true) {
                        combo5();
                    } else if (box2 == true) {
                        combo2();
                    }
                    else{
                        restart();
                    }
                    box2=false;

                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (number == 3) {
                        box3 = true;
                        int count3 = 0;
                    }
                    boolean box3used =false;


                    if (box1 == true && box2 == true && box3 == true) {
                        combo6();
                        box3used =true;
                    } else if (box1 == true && box3 == true) {
                        combo7();
                        box3used =true;
                    } else if (box2 == true && box3 == true) {
                        combo5();
                        box3used =true;
                    }else if (box3 == true) {
                        combo3();
                        box3used = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        restart();
                    }

                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (number == 4) {
                        box4 = true;
                    }
                    if (box5 == true && box4 == true && box3 == true && box2 == true && box1 == true) {
                        combo12();
                    } else if (box4 == true && box2 == true & box3 == true && box1 == true) {
                        combo10();
                    } else if (box4 == true && box2 == true & box1 == true) {
                        combo8();
                    } else {
                        restart();
                    }

                    break;

                case 5:
                    if (number == 5) {
                        box5 = true;
                    }
                    if (box5 == true && box4 == true && box3 == true && box2 == true && box1 == true) {
                        combo12();
                    } else if (box5 == true && box2 == true & box3 == true && box1 == true) {
                        combo11();
                    } else if (box5 == true && box2 == true & box3 == true) {
                        combo9();
                    } else {
                        restart();
                    }
                    break;

                case 6:
                    if (number == 6) {
                        box6 = true;
                    }
                    if (box4 == true && box5 == true) {
                        combo13();
                        gameIsDone = true;
                    } else {
                        restart();
                    }
                    break;

                default:

            }
            System.out.println("Boxes used so far : " + boxesUsedSoFar);
        }
    }


    private static void restart() {
        box1 = false;
        box2 = false;
        box3 = false;
        box4 = false;
        box5 = false;
        box6 = false;
    }
}
```

```
Actual:
Current Box Number : 2
       ___   ___
      |   | |   |
      | 2 | | 3 |
      |___| |___|
Boxes used so far : 49820
Current Box Number : 2
       ___   ___
      |   | |   |
      | 2 | | 3 |
      |___| |___|



Expect:Current Box Number : 2
       ___   ___
      |   | |   |
      | 2 | | 3 |
      |___| |___|
Boxes used so far : 49820
Current Box Number : 2
       ___  
      |   | 
      | 2 | 
      |___|
```

Comment: do you understand why part of this code: switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    if (number == 1) {
                        box1 = true;

                    } is pointless?

Comment: no, im new to coding sorry

Comment: if ( number == 1 ) -> this code will never be executed unless number == 1 has already been tested.

Answer (score 0):

#### You're most of the way there.

I've adjusted a few things:

- You don't need to use an if statement that is redundant with your switch statement.

When you say

```java
switch(number)
case 1:
```

You're technically asking

```java
if(number == 1)
```

So we have no need to check the number inside of the switch statement.

- Simplified checking for a boolean value in an 'if' statement

When checking a boolean variable in an if statement, you don't need to say

```java
if(boolean == true)
```

You can simply say

```java
if(boolean)
```

By default, this checks if the value is true.

As far as the logic on your code goes, I've only shown the parts relevant to your question. You want to check the state of the current box at the beginning of any statement. In the "case:1", the first thing I did was check if box1 was true. If it was, I called the reset method, and kicked us out of the switch statement.

If box1 is false (signifying that we have not used it before), then we can actually run the normal logic, and then set box1 to true. I commented out where some of your logic would go, since I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do with it.

```java
        int boxesUsedSoFar = 0;
        boolean gameIsDone = false;

        while (gameIsDone != true) {
            int number = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            boxesUsedSoFar++;

            System.out.println("Current Box Number : " + number);
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    if (box1) {
                        //box1 is false by default, if it was true here, it means we have a duplicate
                        restart();
                        break;
                    }
                    /*

                    Your code to call a combo method goes here, repeat for each case.

                    */
                    box1 = true;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (box2) {
                        restart();
                        break;
                    }
                    box2 = true;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (box3) {
                        restart();
                        break;
                    }
                    box3 = true;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (box4) {
                        restart();
                        break;
                    }
                    box4 = true;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (box5) {
                        restart();
                        break;
                    }
                    box5 = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (box6) {
                        restart();
                        break;
                    }
                    box6 = true;
                    break;

            }
            System.out.println("Boxes used so far : " + boxesUsedSoFar);
        }
    }
```

If anything here is unclear, please let me know.